# If $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$, does $c_n X_n$ “converge” to $c_n X$?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$. Let $c_n$ denote a bounded, deterministic sequence that does not converge. Is there a sense in which $c_n X_n$ “converges” to $c_n X$?

Answer (score 0):

No.

For example, if $X \sim Bern(0.5)$ and $c_n = (-1)^n$, then $c_n X$ itself doesn't have limit, so we need smth. like $ c_n X_n - c_n X \stackrel{d}{\to} 0$.

Thus  we have $X_n  \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ and want to check if the condition $ c_n X_n - c_n X  = c_n (X_n - X)\stackrel{d}{\to} 0$ holds.

Let us show than even if we have $c_n \to c$ and $X_n  \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ then it doesn't follow that $ c_n (X_n - X)\stackrel{d}{\to} 0$.

**Example 1:** suppose that all $X_n$ are defined on different probability spaces.

And even if all $X_n$ are defined on one different probability space then still nothing works.

**Example 2:** Suppose that $X = 1$ and $X = -1$ with probability $\frac12$, $c_n = 1 =c$, $X_{2n} = X$, $X_{2n-1} = -X$ for all $n\ge 1$. Hence $c_n X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} c_n X$ but it's not true that $ c_n (X_n - X)\stackrel{d}{\to} 0$.

If $c_n \to c$ and $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ then $c_n X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} c X$ by Slutsky's theorem, but it's not what you want.